# Caecilia font for latex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I would like to know if there is a comprehensive website for all (standard) fonts available for latex and their code names.

For example, I would like to use the font [caecilia](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/pmn-caecilia/) and do not know if it is available for latex. If so, I found [this](http://tex.loria.fr/texlive-htmldoc/fontname/fontname_4.html) website from which I gather (CTRL + F, caecilia) that the font family name in latex would be `pil`. Is this correct?

Comment: You're probably after the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)?

Comment: If you want to have the most possibilities in terms of font selection you should take a look at `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`. If you compile your tex-files with either of them, you can load the package `fontspec`, which allows you to use ANY font installed on your computer!

Comment: I don't think it's available. You can use it with `fontinst`: You need to have the `pfb` and `afm` files. From these you can create `.tfm` files (metric files used by TeX), `·vf` (virtual fonts), `.map` files (to let pdflatex and dvips know where are the actual fonts, and `.fd` files (font definition files, for use with LaTeX and NFSS). It's a rather long job, and you can see  the details in the `Font Installation Guide`. The short way consists in loading `fontspec`, and compiling with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, which allows to use *direcly*  any font (truetype or opentype) known to the O.S.

Comment: @Bernard Although the fact that it has a Berry typeface identifier is interesting. It does suggest that support files were available at some point to somebody - or, at least, that somebody planned to make them. (I don't *think* typefaces get names until this point - unless they were assigned with extravagance early on because nobody expected there to ever be a shortage?)

Comment: You can also use `fontinst` to generate files for use with truetype fonts, if you plan to use pdfLaTeX. (Not sure about opentype but definitely works with truetype.) Type 1 are preferable if you can get them, though. (Converting them is an issue: there may be licence restrictions and, in any case, conversion is not without loss.)

Comment: @cfr: they can be converted to type1 format (which doesn't prevent license restrictions) with the LCDF Type Tools.

Comment: @Bernard They can be converted in several ways but going from truetype to type 1 involves some loss of quality because of the different types of curves they are based on, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @cfr: I know that (quadratic splines vs cubic splines), but they're opentype fonts (postscript flavour) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Bernard Then, yes, you're right. My comment was general - I don't know these fonts in particular.

Comment: @cfr: Neither did I. Simply googled to find what they look like.

Comment: @Bernard You know them better than me, in that case ;).